# Setup headless Jenkins slave to login in mac desktop

Tags: macos, ssh, jenkins

There is a main jenkins server which i do not have acess to, which connects through ssh to a jenkins mac slave machine in our office, for mac builds. Since all this is done through ssh, the jenkins never logins in the desktop, and it runs headless.

I have some UI integration tests that i need to run from a bash script file, however the ios simulator requires a desktop session to be on.

This machine has multiple users, and it is accessed through ssh/VNC numerous times per day by key members of our staff, and anyone can logout on the desktop, which would render this solution unusable if someone logs out of the desktop and leaves the office stopping test jobs.

What solutions exist to force desktop login when doing a job/ connecting to the slave machine?

Or if possible anyother solutions, at this moment i am feeling quite desperate as I spent the whole day googling about this.

The jenkins machine runs on mac ox 10.8.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to is just really a work around, we are going to create a node slave in the same machine for just UITesting, and make sure that there is a desktop session at all times, all the existing solutions require vnc login one way or another, if anyone knows a better solution to this, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

I did find this github open source project: https://github.com/plu/pxctest/ which allows for headless simulators. Still looking for other options.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the link moved or broken, your answer will be rendered invalid and deleted. Please provide a summary of what the link contains, and how that answer the OP question.